# Skip Checkout's shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

I have a simple product which consists a custom option, allowing customer to choose Store Pickup / DHL Delivery.

If customer chooses Store Pickup, I want Checkout's entering shipping address page can be skipped.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this?